# How to get standard datetime from tweet.create_at

Tags: python, flask, twitter, tweepy, python-datetime

I am implementing tweepy api in my project and I am trying to get the time a tweet was created using tweet.created_at . It returns a set of Number instead of the actual date string that is shown in the Official twitter API docs. below is the code to get the data:

```
 for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(tweet_api.search, q=user, count=200,
                           lang="en").items(4000):

    if re.match(pattern, tweet.text):
        continue
    tweet_d.append(tweet)

data["text"] = [clean_tweet(tweet.text) for tweet in tweet_d]
data["len"] = [len(clean_tweet(tweet.text)) for tweet in tweet_d]
data["Date"] = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweet_d]
data['Source'] = [tweet.source for tweet in tweet_d]
data['Likes'] = [tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweet_d]
data['RTs'] = [tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweet_d]
```

Here is the Array object printed out:

> [
>     {"text":"b see as you fresh like todays boli",
>     "len":35,
>     "Date":1588602936000,
>     "Source":"Twitter for Android",
>     "Likes":0,
>     "RTs":0},
>     {"text":"b",
>     "len":1,
>     "Date":1588598786000,
>     "Source":"Twitter for Android",
>     "Likes":1,
>     "RTs":0},
>     {"text":"b",
>     "len":1,
>     "Date":1588597919000,
>     "Source":"Twitter for Android",
>     "Likes":1,
>     "RTs":0},]

I am trying to get the Date as standard datetime("Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007",) instead of those set of Numbers shown(1588598786000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number is an UNIX timestamp in milliseconds.

Divide by 1000 to get to seconds, then pass to `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1588602936000 / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 4, 17, 35, 36)
>>> t.isoformat()
'2020-05-04T17:35:36'
```